# Notepad++ replace specific number with up to it's first 4 digit

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find those number which contains more than 5 digits and replace it with first 4 digits.
Used below Regex to find number which contains more than 5 digits.

> [0-9]{5,}

How Can I achieve blow output?

```
99999999 -> this will replace with 9999
12345.66 -> this will replace with 1234.66 
1234 -> Remains unchanged
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should do it:

[image]

The regex

```
([0-9]{4})[0-9]+
```

- takes the four numbers as first (and only) group
- requires at lease one more number behind
- replaces the complete match with the first (and only) group

Comment: Just in case it is relevant, `([0-9]{4})[0-9]+` will match fractional digits in `9.9999999`

Comment: the regex can also be `(\d{4})\d+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's ok for me.

Comment: @GhostOps Woow you are great. Saved lot of my time.

Comment: @GhostOps it is possible to check 5 digit before decimal and 4 digit after decimal?

Comment: @Ajay `\d{5}\.\d{4}`

Comment: @GhostOps Thanks for reply. But I want to check this individually not in combination. First I will check before decimal & then after decimal point

Comment: @Ajay what do u mean by not in combination? that works very well as u want like, it returns only if it has a 5 digit number before decimal and 4 digit after decimal

Answer (score 1):

Using notepad++, you can match 4 digits, then use `\K` to clear the current output buffer and match 1 or more digits.

```
\d{4}\K\d+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/whukrD/1).

In the replacement use an empty string.

[image]

If you don't want partial matches, you can add word boundaries `\b` around the pattern.

```
\b\d{4}\K\d+\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEMZh4/1)